# Output argument not assigned during call (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I'm having a bit of difficulty with this function in  MATLAB and I can't figure out what the issue is. The error is,

```
Output argument "x" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "SDLS".

Error in NO_wk4_Q3c (line 7)
x = SDLS( A, x0, b, 1e-3 );
```

So as far as I know, it's something to do with the output for 'x', yet I have assigned 'x' in the function file. Is it something to do with the 'while' loop?

Below is the function file:

```
function [ x, k ] = SDLS( A, x0, b, tol )
% Steepest descent with exact line search.
% A is the input matrix, x0 is the initial guess, b is a vector, tol is the
% tolerence level for convergence.

if nargin < 4
    tol=eps;
end

g = A*x0+b; % Derivative of Q(x)=(1/2)x'Ax+b'x+c;
p = zeros(1,1);
k = 0;
x=zeros(1,1);

while norm(g,2)>=1e-3
    g = A*x0 + b;
    p = -g; % direction vector
    alpha = -(transpose(g)*p)/(transpose(p)*A*p); % step length
    x = x0 + alpha*p; % updates approximation
    x0 = x;
    k = k+1;
end
end
```

The script file that calls the function is as follows:

```
clear all; 

A = [4 2; 2 3]; % Matrix
x0 = [ -1; -1]; % Initial guess
b = [ 3; 1];

[ x, k] = SDLS( A, x0, b, 1e-3 );
```

Any advice would be great :-)

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that MATLAB is executing? Have you made changes to `SDLS` and not saved them?

Comment: This is the code that MATLAB is executing, I just tested again and i get the same error.

Comment: Restart MATLAB. There is no way for the provided code to generate that error.

Comment: I wrote this code a few days ago, so i've restarted matlab since. I think I will have a talk with my lecturer about it.

Comment: You need to provide more info, the code you just posted cannot generate that error.

Comment: I'm not sure what other information I could provide? Everything is generated in the function file and script file.

Comment: Go to your explorer (or finder on mac) and search for the function. Is it possible that you saved that function on different locations? If so delete or rename all other occurences of the function except this one.

Comment: Renaming the function has fixed the issue, thanks a lot, but maybe I should have thought of that earlier.

Comment: Hence why I asked if you were sure that this was the code MATLAB was executing. [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) will tell you which file MATLAB is calling.

Comment: This is not a proper way to code, you cannot return a variable from a function that is declared and defined inside a loop without previously initialization. Here in your code, how are you so sure that the while loop will get executed for "x" to exist in return?? You have at least to declare it and assign it to zero before the while execution.

Comment: @monakons it is declared before the loop. See `k=0; x=zeros(1,1)` right before the while loop.

Comment: @wildboy you should always be aware that matlab will just execute the FIRST function on your matlab path that is named like your call that it can find. So you should actually never copy functions to multiple locations. At least not on your search path.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I didn't see that. But your code runs perfectly on my machine... that's weird.